# Attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic is not allowed here

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm using flutter.
Androidmanifest has this error.

This is my Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.freshfood">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:label="freshfood"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"

            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
                android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
                android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

error is

Attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic is not allowed here ,
Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here ,
Attribute android:networkSecurityConfig is not allowed here ,
...

I try

1. androidmanifest.xml file sync project with grandle files
2. Invalidate cashes/and restart

I really don't know how to solve it. Please, help me.
Android Studio version is 4.2.1. thank you

Comment: Try moving `networkSecurityConfig` into `<application>`

Comment: I move it but get same error ㅠㅠ

Comment: Open the `android` directory in your flutter project as a separate `Android Project` & sync the project

Comment: oh sepatate project dosent have error but manifest file in original project is stiil error.. Is it OK? thanks..!!